# How to change audio tag when I click on radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I check a html radio button I'd like to change value of my HTML5 audio tag.

Here's my audio tag :

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="test1.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

For example:
If I click on radio button named 'test2.wav I'd like to modify my audio tag like this:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="test2.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Google 'addEventListener"

Comment: Because the OP didn't really put much effort in the question (both in tags and in the question itself that **doesn't** show much effort), I'm not bringing much effort aswell: https://jsfiddle.net/eq4dL1rg/ this may be a starting point, not sure if it works, not sure if it supposed to be, despite it should. Please provide more code next time, what did you try to accomplish the problem? did you suddenly stop after writing the audio tag? no javascript (or jquery, as the tags suggest) is available in your question, and you didn't even provide the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" value="test2" name="rad" onclick="boom(this.value);">test2
<input type="radio" value="test3" name="rad" onclick="boom(this.value);">test3
<input type="radio" value="test4" name="rad" onclick="boom(this.value);">test4
<br>
    <audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="test1.wav" type="audio/wav" id="sound">
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function boom(val){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        var aud = document.getElementById("sound");
        aud.src=val+".wav";
        audio.load();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1jssesz/2/

Comment: Thank you. But I tried your code, it doesn't work. Only the first file is played (test1.wav). If i click on another button 'test2.wav' or 'test3.wav' are not played. Any ideas ? Files are on the server...

Comment: may be you are not giving the correct path to the file. pre-pend the parent path also before the filename.

Comment: I got this error with your code: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByTag is not a function`

Comment: oh Sorry, well no need of that line. removed and updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, add an ID to the `source` tag.

```
<source src="test1.wav" type="audio/wav" id="foo">
```

Next, use a bit of JavaScript, and add an `onclick` attribute to your radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="test2.wav" onclick="document.getElementById('foo').src=this.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="test1.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="track" value="test1.waw" checked> test1.waw<br>
        <input type="radio" name="track" value="test2.waw"> test2.waw<br>
        <input type="radio" name="track" value="test3.waw"> test3.waw
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[type=radio][name=track]").on('change', function(){
          $("audio source").attr("src", $(this).val());
          console.log("new source is: " + $("audio source").attr("src"));
          alert("new source is: " + $("audio source").attr("src"));
        });
        </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```